# Let $f_k \to f$ in $L^{\infty}$, then $f_k \to f$ in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $f_k \to f$ in $L^{\infty}$, then $f_k \to f$ in measure.

I looked at the proof of this statement and it says that it follows from the fact that if $f_k \to f$ in $L^{\infty}$, then $f_k \to f$ uniformly on $N^c$, where $N$ is a null set. However, I am not able to show that the latter statement is true when $f_k \to f$ in $L^\infty$. The definition of the $L^\infty$ norm used here is $\inf_{\mu(N)=0}\sup_{X\setminus N}|f|$. How can I show that this is true? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If $f_k\to f$ in $L^{\infty}$, then for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is an index $k_n$ such that $||f-f_k||_{\infty}<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $k\geq k_n$, hence for each $k\geq k_n$ there is a nullset $N_{k,n}$ such that 
$$ \sup_{X\setminus N_{k,n}}|f_k(x)-f(x)|<\frac{1}{n} $$
Let 
$$N=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=k_n}^{\infty}N_{k,n}$$
then $N$ is a nullset, and $f_k\to f$ uniformly on $X\setminus N$.

Comment: $\|f-f_k\|_\infty \to 0$ here means that there exists a [nullset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set) $N$ such that $f_k \to f$ uniformly on $X \setminus N$ and $\sup_k \sup_{N} |f_k(x)| < \infty$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. What's the issue?